# Resolving error of arguments imply differing number of rows

Tags: raster, r, clip

I downloaded climatic data layers at 5m resolution from worldclim database. I am planning to clip it using Sri Lanka polygon sourced from GDAL library. I made a raster stack of 15 layers using the following code
`bio_stack<-stack(bio1,bio2,bio3,bio4,bio5,bio6,bio7,bio10,bio11,bio12,bio13,bio14,bio15,bio16,bio17)`

Then I cropped it

```
srl<-readOGR("LKA_adm0.shp")
bio_stack_1 <- raster::crop(bio_stack, srl)
bio_stack_2 <- mask(bio_stack_1, srl)
```

Then I run this function from ellipsenm package

```
calib <- ellipsoid_calibration(data_split, species = "Species", longitude = "longitude", 
                               latitude = "latitude", variables = variable_sets,
                               methods = methods, level = 95, selection_criteria = "S_OR_P",
                               error = 5, iterations = 500, percentage = 50,
                               output_directory = "calibration_results", overwrite = TRUE)
```

But I get the following error

> Error in data.frame(xy_train, na.omit(raster::extract(varss, xy_train))) :
> arguments imply differing number of rows: 30, 26

[image: cropped raster and points]

The objects in the argument:

```
data_split <- split_data(K_OCC, method = "random", longitude =  "longitude", latitude = "latitude", train_proportion = 0.70, 
                         save = TRUE, name = "K")
methods <- c("covmat", "mve1")
sets <- list(set_1 = c("bio1", "bio2"),
             set_2 = c("bio1", "bio3","bio3"),
             set_3 = c("bio1", "bio2", "bio3", "bio4"),
             set_4 = c("bio1", "bio2", "bio3", "bio4", "bio13"),
             set_5 = c("bio1", "bio2", "bio3", "bio4", "bio13","bio14")) 
bio_stack_2_F<-subset(bio_stack_2, c("bio1","bio2","bio3","bio4","bio13","bio14"))

variable_sets <- prepare_sets(bio_stack_2_F, sets)
```

[![raster and points][2]][2]

```
> K_OCC
    Species longitude latitude
1   Species  80.65913  7.32286
12  Species  81.01955  7.46462
20  Species  80.36088  7.48176
21  Species  79.83527  7.37062
22  Species  79.92600  7.68448
23  Species  79.94879  7.77836
24  Species  80.12638  7.65505
25  Species  79.87239  7.35628
26  Species  79.81636  7.41750
27  Species  79.92579  7.68439
28  Species  80.33364  7.51774
29  Species  79.91087  7.49240
30  Species  80.28787  7.98649
31  Species  79.93721  7.59822
32  Species  79.82687  7.57059
80  Species  81.59010  7.78598
81  Species  81.79460  7.52937
82  Species  81.78041  7.58799
83  Species  81.72657  7.68555
84  Species  81.79832  7.52993
85  Species  81.63638  7.47776
86  Species  81.72640  7.68521
87  Species  81.85159  7.21958
88  Species  81.78461  7.57963
89  Species  81.78583  7.58131
90  Species  81.72692  7.68516
91  Species  81.04648  7.67127
92  Species  81.68333  7.56666
93  Species  81.26840  8.45790
94  Species  81.83063  7.41438
95  Species  81.73220  7.39113
96  Species  81.76913  7.51916
127 Species  81.17579  7.76984
128 Species  80.63659  8.25437
141 Species  81.00236  6.31936
142 Species  80.19029  6.09216
143 Species  80.73827  6.12250
214 Species  80.18053  9.67835
215 Species  79.98361  8.88589
227 Species  79.86649  7.20323
228 Species  79.90136  7.14063
229 Species  80.24354  6.94499
309 Species  80.84331  6.31623
```

Comment: https://github.com/marlonecobos/ellipsenm (ELLIPSENM PACKAGE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem:

In the cropped raster, some of points fell outside the raster, and NAs were in the extracted values. I deleted those occurrence points, and now the function works.